# How to capture two finger event in javascript on Mac?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am building a website with reactjs. The main DOM I am using is `Canvas` and users are allowed to move around the web page with the two fingers gesture on Mac OS. If the user move to the left side of the canvas it will trigger a navigator event on the browser to go back. How can I stop the go back event on browser?

I know I can disable the two fingers swipe gesture in system Trackpad configuration. But I don't want to do that since it doesn't seem like a good solution from users' point of view.

Comment: Were you able to find anything to work around this ?